# SQL Rounding result to 5 decimals, I want the full result

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I am no math expert or SQL expert (Microsoft SQL Server 2017) for that matter so I have no idea why this is happening.

So my Query is `((1000000000*0.00002 * POWER(10, (82.6 / 20))) / 1000000000) AS FJS`

Now for some reason the result is **0.2697800000000000** or **0.26978**, but when I put the exact same query in a calculator or google the result is **0.26979257651**
The sum I put in google is

`(1000000000*0.00002*(10^(82.6/20)))/1000000000`

or

[use this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=(1000000000*0.00002*(10%5E(82.6/20)))/1000000000)

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Your first argument to `POWER` is an `INT` literal, so the result is an `INT` as well. Change the `10` to `10e` to make it a `FLOAT`.

Comment: Obtaining an overly precise result when your inputs have limited precision doesn't make the more precise result more "accurate". You only have about 5 digits of precision in any of your inputs. Why do you think that 0.26979257651 is "more right" than 0.26978?

Comment: `1000000000*0.00002*POWER(10, 82.6 / 20) = 269780000.00000`  0.26978 right result

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert thanks a lot man that is f'ing awesome! please answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the result of `POWER(10, (82.6 / 20))` is `13489`, which is a long way off from the precise value. This is because `POWER` returns the type of its input, which in this case is `INT`. This is not particularly helpful, but it *is* [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql#return-types)<sup>[1]</sup>.

The fix is to make  the first argument a `FLOAT`, which brings the rest of the expression in line as well. The easiest way to do that is to tack on an `e`, so:

```
SELECT ((1000000000*0.00002 * POWER(10e, (82.6 / 20))) / 1000000000)
```

gives `0.269792576518331`. If you prefer, `CAST(10 AS FLOAT)` would do as well. Using `10.0` would *not* do, because this literal is of type `DECIMAL(3,1)`, and `POWER(10.0, (82.6/20))` is `13489.6`, which is not much better than what we started off with.

---

[1]: the documentation, however, is wrong when it says the output type is `DECIMAL(2,0)` if the input type is: in my test, passing in a `DECIMAL` of any precision results in a `DECIMAL` of precision 38, not the original precision. There are other anomalies as well. I've submitted a pull request to correct this.